# Need XSLT for copying inner xml comes as string from a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that I would like to Transform.

> XML

```
<Process xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <Result>-1</Result>
 <Id>qwer1234</Id>
 <xml>
 <![CDATA[<hello type="PROCESS"><process urn="hello"><object></object><object></object></process></hello>]]>
</xml>
</Process>
```

I would like to retrieve inner xml from the  tag.

> XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xsl:template match="/Process">
  <xsl:value-of select="xml" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the above xslt, if the namespace (xmlns="http://tempuri.org/") is not available in the input xml, I am able to get the desired output. But with namespace, I am unable to get the desired output.

> Desired Output

```
<hello type="PROCESS">
 <process urn="hello">
  <object></object>
  <object></object>
 </process>
</hello>
```

I am new to use of XSLT. I will be helpful I can produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the prefix, but you're not using it. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns:Process">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:xml)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. When I tried, I used on the root node, but not on the desired select node.

Comment: But when I apply the retrieved xml to an xsd, I get this error 'Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it'

Comment: Still having issues, the xml that I receive does not have CData around the inner xml node and throwing the exception. Your solution works perfect for the question I asked. XML that I receive is in wrong format as per my understanding if it does not come with CData.

Comment: @Kabali Ask a new question.

Comment: Sure, I will post a new question.